# Retrieve retweeters id

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I need to retrieve retweeters id using tweepy.

```
import tweepy
import time,json

APP_KEY=""
APP_SECRET=""
OAUTH_TOKEN=""
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET=""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
'''for status in api.user_timeline(screen_name='acmigdtuw',include_rts=1,count=200):
    print status.id'''
firstTweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name="acmigdtuw")[0]
print firstTweet.text
print firstTweet.id
#results = api.retweets(status.id,cursor=-1,stringify_ids=1) 
pl = api.retweets.id(id=firstTweet.id) 
print pl[0]['user']['screen_name']
```

Comment: try `pl = api.retweets(firstTweet.id)` on the next-to-last line. then change last line to `print pl` will print `862193390158532608`

Comment: thankx @downshift for reply: actually i want to print id of all retweeters,how can i achieve this? please help... I tried your solution,it giving me verbose details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
firstTweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name="acmigdtuw")[0]

# get the original tweet
original_tweet = firstTweet.retweeted_status.id

# iterate over retweets to get user id
for status in api.retweets(original_tweet):
    print status.user.id
```

output:

```
839110314012598272
390229046
```

These are the IDs of the users who retweeted the original tweet.

We can confirm by comparing the number of retweets to our results:

```
print firstTweet.retweeted_status.retweet_count == len(api.retweets(original_tweet))
```

> True

Comment: wow, finally the logic was in original tweet... @downshift you uplifted me. thankx a lot sir... u saved life :) thanx once again

Comment: According to tweepy documentation, it will only return up to 100 retweeters ids. Is there a way to retrieve more than that?

Comment: @ysearka check this answer, [Tweepy get retweeters returning max 100](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502159/1248974)